# how to do a grails findAllBy with one to many relationship

Tags: grails, findall

I have a one to many relationship between User and Task and want to get all of the tasks for that user, but my query isn't returning any results. Here's what I have:

```
def getByStatus(String findBy) {
    // either get by Open/Closed or by All.
    def sortPref = [sort: "deadline", order: "asc"]
    def u = User.get(session.user.id) // session.user is a user domain object

    if (findBy != "All")
        tasks = Task.findAllByUserAndStatus(u, findBy, sortPref)
    else
        tasks = Task.findAllByUser(u, sortPref) 

}
```

I also tried searching by .findByUserIdAndStatus, but got an error saying that there was no UserId property on task. If I remove the user part, then I get all of the tasks.

Comment: Please show your User and Task models

Comment: Is status just a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no issue with lazy loading (assuming # of tasks per user is not considerably high), you can directly get required tasks based on user (from 1:M relationship) as:

```
def getByStatus(String findBy) {
    // either get by Open/Closed or by All.
    def u = User.get(session.user.id) // session.user is a user domain object

    def tasks = findBy == 'All' ? u.tasks.sort{it.deadline} :
                      u.tasks.findAll{it.status == findBy}.sort{it.deadline}
}
```

If interested, you can have the `sort` set in the mapping of the domain class.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly! I will look into applying the sort to the mapping of the domain class.